# Shorcuts within the scala REPL

Tags: scala

Some basic keyboard movement commands are apparently elusive in the `REPL` :
 - (Line) Home
 - (Line) End
 - Word forward/back

Something tells me I have used these in the `REPL` in the past; so there should be some procedure to engage them.

I am on OS/X Sierra and interested in the shortcuts primarily on scala 2.11 (though notes about 2.10 also appreciated).

**Update** `Control-a|e` do *not* work: I had tried all combinations of modifier keys with `a|e` before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala Repl is using the **emacs** keybinding.

so for:

`Home` ->  `C-a`

`End` -> `C-e`

more **keymapping** you can find it in `Emacs Shortcut Wiki`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html

also you can toggle it to `vi` mode by `Esc+Enter`

Comment: Control-A is not working (would not have posted this if it did ..).  This is likely a mac-specific issue.

Comment: Could you check the `~/.inputrc` or the system **keymapping** whether the keymapping is overrided.

Comment: Oh i see as part of this exercise i had created an `~/.inputrc`. I had created it after starting look into this but before trying out `ctrl-a|` which do work. thx